# hibernate createAlias with clause generates wrong query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have the following tables:
A: id
B: id, text
AB: aID, bID

I want to joib A and B where B.text contains the word 'cat'.

This is the hibernate query I do:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(TableA.class, "A");
c.createAlias("A.bs", "B", JoinType.INNER_JOIN, Restrictions.like("b.text", "%cat%"));
c.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
```

The generated query is:

```
Select id 
FROM A a
INNER JOIN AB ab ON a.id=ab.aID AND (b.text like ?)
INNER JOIN B b ON b.id=ab.bID AND (b.text like ?)
```

For some reason `AND (b.text like ?)` appears in both inner joins. I far as I understand its supposed to be only in the second on.
This causes the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
```

I guess it's happening because it has only one parameters and two '?'.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Adding the persistent classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
Class A {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", length=255)
    protected String id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="AB", joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="aID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="bID"))
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    protected List<B> bs;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
Class B {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", length=255)
    protected String id;

    @Column(name="text", length=255)
    protected String text;

}
```

Comment: Please, show your persistent classes

Comment: Please see the classes above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create an alias

```
c.createAlias("A.bs", "b", JoinType.INNER_JOIN, Restrictions.like("b.text", "%cat%"));
```

**Updated**

I think It is a Hibernate bug. You can fix it by using a restriction in the `where` clause

```
 c.createAlias("A.bs", "b", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
 c.add(Restrictions.like("b.text", "%cat%"));
```

or don't use join table and do association by foreign key in `B`.

Comment: My fault, this is indeed what I'm doing. Its A.bs not A.id

Comment: @julius_am what about `"B"` in your example

Comment: These are all typos in my example. Everything works fine with c.createAlias("A.bs", "B") but when I add the third and forth parameters I get an exception and wrong query is generated. I'm afraid this is a hibernate bug but I don't have a work around

Comment: Your update is an optional solution but I'm afraid that it's less efficient because in this case it will perform JOIN on all rows and only then cut the non relevant rows from the where, while in the first suggestion it'll cut before performing the JOIN, isn't it?

Comment: @julius_am I think, a database optimizer will do all work fine, but anyway you can test two plain SQL queries and compare performance of two approaches. And what about an association by a foreign key?

Comment: @julius_am try to use `sqlRestriction` with alias may be it helps